# Flow with multiple outbound HTTP calls

Tags: spring-integration

We have a shopping cart domain model with line items. Externally, we have a single API to checkout the shopping cart. Internally though, we have 3 distinct HTTP services:

1. Create shopping cart
2. Add line item(s) - one HTTP call per line item
3. Checkout

We'd like to express this in an integration flow, aborting if any of the steps fail or timeout. Here is some pseudo code for the flow:

```
 @Bean
public IntegrationFlow cartFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(channel())
            .transform(fromJson(ShoppingCart.class))
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway(.....) // How do we proceed here to create a shopping cart?
            .split(ShoppingCart.class, ShoppingCart::getLineItems)
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway(.....) // And here to add each line item?
            .aggregate()
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway(.....) // And here to checkout
            .get();
}
```

Adding the Http.outboundGateway calls isn't an issue. The question really is about preserving context (about the ShoppingCart after the HTTP method invocation). The services don't return any data beyond confirming that the call succeeded.

One option I understand is to create a custom bean which makes the HTTP calls and inject that into the pipeline. That approach doesn't feel very idiomatic to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use-case fully fit to the `Content Enricher` [pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DataEnricher.html), with which you have some `payload`, call some external service (via gateway on the `request-channel`), wait for the reply and add some content to the original `payload`.

For your use-case you might need several consequential `.enrich()` definitions.

Also see Spring Integration `Content Enricher` [definition](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#payload-enricher) for more information.

**EDIT**

`ContentEnricher` sample:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow enricherFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("enricherInput", true)
            .enrich(e -> e.requestChannel("enrichChannel")
                    .requestPayloadExpression("payload")
                    .shouldClonePayload(false)
                    .propertyExpression("name", "payload['name']")
                    .propertyFunction("date", m -> new Date())
                    .headerExpression("foo", "payload['name']")
            )
            .get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there an example of this you can point me to? Appreciate your help as I get ramped up with using spring integration.

Comment: Please, find a sample in my answer.

Comment: Not exactly sure I understand the example. As you mention in the explanation of your answer, there is a need to call an external service. So I expect to be able to configure a uri, the http method, the response type etc. as part of the enrichment. I'm most likely missing this

Comment: Look, there is a `e.requestChannel("enrichChannel")`. You should configure a new `IntegrationFlow` on that channel and perform your HTTP request, indeed. For more information, please, read Reference Manual.

Comment: Thanks for being patient. I was trying to avoid creating a new flow. To be more specific, I was trying to do something similar to what camel allows: http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html (see the "Using dynamic URIs) section.

Comment: H-m. Actually to make your code more cleaner it really would be better to distinguish your complex logic to small logical `IntegrationFlow`s. You can consider to use `.gateway(IntegrationFlow flow)` for similar purpose with a sub-flow definition.

Comment: Created a sample on github. The configuration code is available in [Application.java](https://github.com/premanandc/api-gateway-sample/blob/master/api-gateway/src/main/java/com/premonition/Application.java). This is nowhere close to production grade, just an illustration.

Comment: You can minimize your config getting rid off all those `DirectChannel` bean definitions. SI Java DSL just takes care about them via provided names.