# Enriching in parallel after a split

Tags: spring-integration

This is a continuation of the [shopping cart sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428134/flow-with-multiple-outbound-http-calls/38447816#38447816), where we have an external API that allows checkout from a shopping cart. To recap, we have a flow where we create an empty shopping, add line item(s) and finally checkout. All the operations above, happen as enrichments through HTTP calls to an external service. We would like to add line items concurrently (as part of the add line items) call. Our current configuration looks like this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fullCheckoutFlow() {
    return f -> f.channel("inputChannel")
            .transform(fromJson(ShoppingCart.class))
            .enrich(e -> e.requestChannel(SHOPPING_CART_CHANNEL))
            .split(ShoppingCart.class, ShoppingCart::getLineItems)
            .enrich(e -> e.requestChannel(ADD_LINE_ITEM_CHANNEL))
            .aggregate(aggregator -> aggregator
                    .outputProcessor(g -> g.getMessages()
                            .stream()
                            .map(m -> (LineItem) m.getPayload())
                            .map(LineItem::getName)
                            .collect(joining(", "))))
            .enrich(e -> e.requestChannel(CHECKOUT_CHANNEL))
            .<String>handle((p, h) -> Message.called("We have " + p + " line items!!"));
}

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow addLineItem(Executor executor) {
        return f -> f.channel(MessageChannels.executor(ADD_LINE_ITEM_CHANNEL, executor).get())
                .handle(outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/api/add-line-item", restTemplate())
                        .httpMethod(POST)
                        .expectedResponseType(String.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor executor(Tracer tracer, TraceKeys traceKeys, SpanNamer spanNamer) {
        return new TraceableExecutorService(newFixedThreadPool(10), tracer, traceKeys, spanNamer);
    }
```

To add line items in parallel, we are using an executor channel. However, they still seem to be getting processed sequentially when seen in zipkin:

[image: Zipkin trace]

What are we doing wrong? The source for the whole project is on [github](https://github.com/premanandc/api-gateway-sample) for reference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the main feature of Spring Integration is `MessageChannel`, but it still isn't clear to me why people are missing `.channel()` operator in between endpoint definitions.

I mean that for your case it must be like:

```
.split(ShoppingCart.class, ShoppingCart::getLineItems)
.channel(c -> c.executor(executor()))
.enrich(e -> e.requestChannel(ADD_LINE_ITEM_CHANNEL))
```

Now about your particular problem.

Look, `ContentEnricher` (`.enrich()`) is request-reply component: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#payload-enricher.

Therefore it sends request to its `requestChannel` and waits for reply. And it is done independently of the `requestChannel` type.

I raw Java we can demonstrate such a behavior with this code snippet:

```
for (Object item: items) {
    Data data = sendAndReceive(item);
}
```

where you should see that `ADD_LINE_ITEM_CHANNEL` as an `ExecutorChannel` doesn't have much value because we are blocked within loop for the reply anyway.

A `.split()` does exactly similar loop, but since by default it is with the `DirectChannel`, an iteration is done in the same thread. Therefore each next item waits for the reply for the previous.

That's why you definitely should parallel exactly as an input for the `.enrich()`, just after `.split()`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So, in effect we are doing splitter -> executor channel -> enrich. And the executor channel is one that enables parallelization. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct. And that enricher's requestChannel as an executor one does not make sense, because we are blocked for waiting for reply anyway.